# React Routing implementation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, routes

I am trying to implement routing in my react app. So I have a component with navigation to another components:

```
  class Order extends Component {

        render() {

            return (
                <div>
                     <ul>
                       <li>
                         <Link to="/stepOne/">1</Link>
                        </li>
                       <li>
                        <Link to="/stepTwo/">2</Link>
                       </li>
                          <Link to="/stepThree/">3</Link>
                        <li>
                           <Link to="/steFour/">4</Link>
                        </li>
                     </ul>

                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/stepOne" component={SearchConcoctionFormula} />
                        <Route exact path="/stepTwo" component={OrderStepTwoIndex} />
                        <Route exact path="/stepThree" component={OrderStepThreeIndex} />
                        <Route exact path="/stepFour" component={OrderStepFourIndex} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>);
        }
    }

    export default Order;
```

But my problem is that when I click on the link, the selected component is rendered along with the navigation links. 
But I expect only the selected component to be rendered. What should I change?

Comment: create links component separately and onload render that component first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Order extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component= 
                        {Links} />
                   <Route exact path="/stepOne" component= 
                        {SearchConcoctionFormula} />
                    <Route exact path="/stepTwo" component= 
                       {OrderStepTwoIndex} 
                    />
                    <Route exact path="/stepThree" component= 
                        {OrderStepThreeIndex} />
                    <Route exact path="/stepFour" component= 
                      {OrderStepFourIndex} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>);
    }
}

export default Order;
```

create new component

```
class Links extends Component {
 render(){
      <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/stepOne/">1</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
          <Link to="/stepTwo/">2</Link>
          </li>
          <Link to="/stepThree/">3</Link>
          <li>
          <Link to="/steFour/">4</Link>
          </li>
         </ul>
   }
}
export default Links
```

something like this,also Wrap with Router